# How to change Element color in HarmonyOS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am creating a custom component in HarmonyOS using Java SDK, Where I need to change Element color at runtime.

In Android we have `setTint()` api to change color of drawable at runtime.

for ex:

```
drawable.setTint(Color.BLUE); //Require Api level 21
OR
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.BLUE);
```

but, In HMOS I saw there is no any api like `setTint()` or `setColor()` to change color of Element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color of the icon using `setColorMatrix` from the `Element` class.

```
public static void setIconColor(Element icon, Color color) {
    int iColor = color.getValue();
    int red   = (iColor & 0xFF0000) / 0xFFFF;
    int green = (iColor & 0xFF00) / 0xFF;
    int blue  = iColor & 0xFF;
    float[] matrix = {
            0, 0, 0, 0, red,
            0, 0, 0, 0, green,
            0, 0, 0, 0, blue,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };
    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setMatrix(matrix);
    icon.setColorMatrix(colorMatrix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the element color by referring to the following code:

```
ShapeElement shapeElementWhite = new ShapeElement();

shapeElementWhite.setRgbColor(new RgbColor(255,255,255)); // Set Color Using Numbers

shapeElementWhite.setRgbColor(RgbColor.fromArgbInt(0xADD8E6)); // Set Color Using Hexadecimal

Component component = findComponentById(ResourceTable.Id_buy_train);

component.setBackground(shapeElementWhite);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But this solution is not working for me, because in my case Element is type of VectorElement or PixleMapElement.